# How to declare dictionary type in parameter?

Tags: swift

How do I declare a dictionary in a parameter using convenience syntax?

```
init(mydictionary:[Int: String]())
{...}
```

Comment: Why not `init(mydictionary:[Int: String]) {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only problem is that you were initializing the dictionary in the parameters, took me a while to see.

Try this:

```swift
init(mydictionary:[Int: String])
{...}
```